# Alphanumeric (sha1) Semaphore in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, semaphore, sha

PHP's "shm_get" function requires an integer semaphore key, which I realise to be a restriction of the underlying OS.

I am using the "sha1" function to hash some user input and using the hash to uniquely identify a number of resulting files and and background processes.

Is there a way to convince shm_get to accept an alphanumeric key or to convert a sha1 hash to an acceptable integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a hexadecimal number into a decimal number by using [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

However if you have got a large number in your hash, this won't return an integer. But you need an integer. So you might want to cut it apart and only use a part of the hash.

```
$hash = sha1('http://www.hashcat.net/');
$hash = substr($hash, 0, 15); // ok on 64bit systems
$number = (int) hexdec($hash); // cap to PHP_INT_MAX anyway
var_dump($hash, $number);
```

Comment: There is no way you will store that number in an integer.. substr it first.

Comment: hexdec doesn't guarantee an integer return. This seems as though it could be a problem.

Comment: As long as it doesn't trigger [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), it will return an integer. However, I'll cap it with a cast. - Edited. And yeah it triggers @ 16 > 7FFF..., so edited.